# long long int don't take long int well

Tags: c++, printf

When a friend of mine asked me to debug the problem with a console game project I had found a weird conversion of fprintf in C that I can't figure out. The project was required to keep track of all the information, including scores and update time to a `.txt` file using C.

-Initialization

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
.
.
.
// in main
    time_t timer;
    time (&timer);
    int num=0,c;
    scanf(" %s %ld", inputname,c);
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
    num++;
    char **name;
    long *times;
    ull *score;

    name = new char *[num];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        name[i] = new char[MAX];
    }
    times = new long [num];
    score = new ull[num];

    //new data
    name[num-1] = inputname;
    score[num-1] = c;
    times[num-1] = timer;
```

-The I/O parts

```c
.
.
.
// input from file after dynamic variables have fix size
    for(int i=0; i<num-1; i++){
        fscanf(fp, " %s%d", name[i], &score[i]);
        fscanf(fp, "%ld", &times[i]);
    }

    fseek(fp , 0 , SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", num);

//print back to fp
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){

        fprintf(fp, "%s %ld ",name[i], score[i]);
        fprintf(fp, "%ld\n",times[i]);  
    }
```

---

Problem. if I change

```c
    fprintf(fp, "%s %ld ",name[i], score[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "%ld\n",times[i]);
```

to one-line

```c
fprintf(fp, "%s %ld %ld\n",name[i], score[i],times[i]);
```

the output file will have

```
NAME1 SCORE1 TIMEINLONG1
NAME2 SCORE2 0
NAME3 SCORE3 0
.
.
.
```

instead of

```
NAME1 SCORE1 TIMEINLONG1
NAME2 SCORE2 TIMEINLONG2
.
.
.
```

---

After some trying, I found that by reversing the order of scores and times

```c
fprintf(fp, "%s %ld %ld\n",name[i], times[i],score[i]);
```

I have a correct output

```
NAME1 TIMEINLONG1 SCORE1
.
.
.
```

again.

So, how exactly does C do with output stream. I thought the compiler collect the argument in `"..."` to assemble a string, then flush it to outputstream. Obviously it ignored the time[i] after the first (time[0]).

Is it the problem of the way I intialize times[]?
Or is it the problem with fprintf()?

Apology for such a lengthy page, but I'm really confused about the `fprint` now.

---

### Solved

#### edit title from "fprintf with dynamic memory" to "long long int don't take long int well, vise versa."

The problem was not on the dynamic memory things(Sorry I didn't know), but was the type that I used to get and put data in printf, fprintf, scanf, fscanf. According to @Adrian Mole , the **mismatch** assign long int to a long long int type variables was **undefined behavior**, and the following I/O action will not be correctly done. It seems that even long long int have more space than those of long long, it is not compatible.

*No*

```c
long long int c;
scanf("%d",&c);
printf("%d",c);
//or
scanf("%ld",&c);
printf("%ld",c);
```

*Yes*

```c
long long int c;
scanf("%lld",&c);
printf("%lld",c);
```

Comment: You are inconsistent when using pointers.  scanf takes a pointer address.

Comment: %ld is incorrect for unsigned long long. Probably fprintf is getting the top 32 bits of the score and treating that as the time. I assume that ull is unsigned long long.

Comment: You have undefined behaviour already while reading `c` as `%ld` is not suitable to read an `int.

Comment: You should tag this question as C++ because it is clearly not C.

Comment: @thebusybee sorry I thought I was on C, editing it

Answer (score 3):

You have here a classic example of "undefined behaviour!" The variable that is `score[i]` is (assuming a reasonable definition of the type `ull`) an **unsigned long long int** (possibly/probably 64-bits) but both the `scanf` and 'offending' `printf` calls use the `%ld` format specifier (possibly/probably referring to a 32-bit variable).

When `printf` is called with a "mismatch" between the format specifier and the given argument, you are in **undefined behaviour** territory!

Fix the issue by specifying the `%llu` format for the corresponding `score[i]` argument! For example, in place of:

```c
fprintf(fp, "%s %ld %ld\n",name[i], score[i],times[i]);
```

use:

```c
fprintf(fp, "%s %llu %ld\n", name[i], score[i], times[i]);
// score[i] is ull ^ | ^ OK - times[i] is (signed) long!
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Hmm - not sure I'm ready for 'almost perfect', but see the latest edit.

Comment: Yeah, it work well. I thought it was the problem with the conversion between time_t and long int. Turn out it was  the type I used for I/O of score

Comment: But does it mean that C did have suitable conversion to assign long int to long long int?

Answer (score 1):

The problems start at the following lines:

```
int num=0,c;
scanf(" %s %ld", inputname, c);
```

First, you should write `&c` instead of `c` as the last parameter. Since scanf writes into its parameters, it should receive addresses of parameters (except strings, I am too lazy to explain why).

Second, since  `c` is `int`, you need `%d`, not `%ld`.  Be careful with sizes.

As for your fprintf - again, be careful with sizes. Since `score` is `ull*`, and I assume that `ull` means `unsigned long long`, you need to print it with `%llu` format, not `%ld`. (Note - Andrian Mole also pointed this piece, and posted his answer slightly before I posted mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Another error is:

```
name[num-1] = inputname;
```

That reassigns the pointer to heap allocated memory and causes a memory leak. `inputname` array should be copied into `name[n]` array, e.g.,

```
snprintf(name[num-1], MAX, "%s", inputname);
```

---

`scanf` `%s` may overflow its destination array argument, unless you hard-code the destination size, e.g.:

```
#define MAX 256
int num=0,c;
char inputname[MAX];
scanf("%256s %d", inputname, c);
```

Comment: Thx for answering. You mean that it's better if we take the string by copying  a certain length instead of direct assignment?